# Unicode character issue in SQL - Indian Rupee

Tags: unicode, sql-server-2008-r2, currency

I am trying to insert the new Indian Rupee symbol into the database, but it is not working. Here is some sample code to illustrate:

```
DECLARE @symbolData TABLE ( SomeSymbol nvarchar(100))
INSERT @symbolData VALUES(N'лв');
INSERT @symbolData VALUES(N'र');
INSERT @symbolData VALUES(N'₹');
SELECT * FROM @symbolData

SELECT N'र' AS 'Char', UNICODE(N'र') AS 'Unicode value', NCHAR(UNICODE(N'र')) AS 'Created Char'
UNION ALL
SELECT N'₹' AS 'Char', UNICODE(N'₹') AS 'Unicode value', NCHAR(UNICODE(N'₹')) AS 'Created Char'
```

In the 2nd select, you can see that the first character is displayed correctly, but the 2nd one is not. I am running this on SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50) SP1.

Comment: Which sql are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50) SP1 and Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Comment: It works if you switch output to text instead of grid. It has probably to do with the font used in the grid.

Comment: @Mikael once again, Eagle-Eye Cherry